# Check all ComboBox items and do +1

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following items in my `ComboBox`.
[prtscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEyqv.png)

I would like the output to be the highest number + 1 so: 015 <----

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Im Sorry What do you mean by Highest number +1

Comment: The item with the highest number because the project numbers are from 001 to ***. and I want vba to automatically choose the next project number for me.

Comment: Will identifing the Combobox value with Highest number server your purpose? What is your next step once you identify the Highest item?

Comment: Well, when it's 21I want it to become 22. Then I create a new folder with the project name and number 22. :D

Comment: Sorry Let me take this example, Now that I have Values from 'Val001-Val020' Now that i found the highest value in Combobox is Val020. So Are expecting to add a new value to Combobox as Val021?

Comment: That's right :D finally someone who understand my shitty explanation

Comment: Okay! Now I understand... Please update you question to include the correct explanation (as given by @Siva) and an example if possible (instead of a screenshot). You should update the Title too! More members will be susceptible to answer your question if you do so! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code Help you iterate through all the value and find the Maximum value of the drop down values. Looking at the screenshot. Modify according to your need.

```
Sub AddHighPlusOne()
Dim cb As ComboBox
Set cb = ActiveSheet.ComboBox22
maxValue = 0
For i = 1 To cb.ListCount - 1
  'Looking at your scrren shot i see that, number is in middle, so i used Mid here. 
  'Please change the values as per your need
  If (CInt(Mid(cb.List(i), 6, 1)) > maxValue) Then 
      maxValue = CInt(Mid(cb.List(i), 6, 1))
  End If

Next
'maxValue will be the highest value
'cb.AddItems("UrPrefix" & maxValue & "Ur Suffix ")

End Sub
```

Comment: Error in the script. Set cb = ActiveSheet.ComboBox4 <- I have the error over here

Comment: If your combo box is from userform , use UserForm.Combo box, else check the sheet in which combobox is present is active before that line